# How to run a tkinter application without python console

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am beginner and I don't know how can I run a tkinter window without python console ,I have tried by saving file with .pyw extensions but it opens nothing it would be great if someone tells how to close terminal after a few seconds of opening application

Comment: You want to make an exe? Then take a look at `pyinstaller`. Otherwise, in the terminal, saying `python filename.py` will run the app and there will not be any console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to convert .py to .exe then check this post about it https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-tkinter-to-exe-with-cx-freeze/

It should run if you open the .exe file.